# Case when in Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Untested waters,I'm trying to find a way to ease things up. Instead of having a nested select in a cursor in PL-SQL. I'm trying to make a case when in the cursor. Since the cursor can have different inparameters and I need to sort things accordingly.

Is this possible? My code looks like this. It's easy to read ao_in is the Inparam.

```
PROCEDURE theProcedure (ao_in IN VARCHAR2)

CURSOR order_cur
  IS
 Case when ao_in = 'NIEC' 
  then          
      SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
      FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
      WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
      AND ao_in =
                     DECODE (ao_in, 'NIEC', ao_in, get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr))
              AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
     ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;

  when ao_in = 'DSSP'  then
  SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
      FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
      WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
      AND ao_in =
                     DECODE (ao_in, 'DSSP', ao_in, get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr))
              AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
     ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;
  when ao_in = 'ALLA'

  SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
      FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
      WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
      AND ao_in =
                     DECODE (ao_in, 'ALLA', ao_in, get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr))
              AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
     ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;
  end
```

Comment: ao_in is a parameter for the procedure. Is it a column in the table as well? Because if it is not I fail to see the logic of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can't use a `case` to run different statements. A (SQL) case can only be used to return a single (column) value. You need three cursors and then when you _open_ the cursor you need to check the parameter and open the correct one.

Comment: @ahorsewithnoname what about union all and where condition checking the parameter value ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want could be done with the [OPEN-FOR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems033.htm) statement, like this:

```
PROCEDURE theProcedure (ao_in IN VARCHAR2)

    TYPE t_cur IS REF CURSOR;
    order_cur t_cur;

begin
    Case when ao_in = 'NIEC' 
      then  
        open order_cur for 
              SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
              FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
              WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
                AND ao_in = 'NIEC'
                AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
             ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;

      when ao_in = 'DSSP'  then
        open order_cur for
              SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
              FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
              WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
                AND ao_in = 'DSSP'
                AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
             ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;
      when ao_in = 'ALLA'
        open order_cur for
            SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
            FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
            WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
                AND ao_in ='ALLA'
                AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
         ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;
    end;
end;
```

Notice that the decode evaluation for the ao_in parameter is not necessary, since is already been evaluated in the case statement.
I assume that order_in is declared somewhere in the original code and not posted here for simplification, otherwise it should be declared.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a column called "ao_in" in your eh_order_t@ngext_dblink table, I think what you're after is something like this:

```
PROCEDURE theProcedure (p_ao_in IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  CURSOR order_cur
  IS
    SELECT t1.nr,
           t1.status$nr
    FROM   eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
    WHERE  t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
    AND    (p_ao_in in ('NIEC', 'DSSP', 'ALLA')
            OR
            (p_ao_in not in ('NIEC', 'DSSP', 'ALLA') and ao_in = get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr)))
    AND    t1.nr = COALESCE(order_in, t1.nr)
    ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;
BEGIN
  FOR order_rec in order_cur
  LOOP
    -- do the things
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Alternatively, you could have two cursors, one that selects everything, and one that filters on the ao_in column, and then call the relevant one depending on which parameter is passed in. I believe that Oracle should be able to optimise the above combined cursor based on the parameter passed in, but if you found it couldn't or wanted to make sure, splitting the cursor into two separate ones would help the optimzer.

It is important that you shouldn't use the same parameter or variable name in your cursors within PL/SQL, as the optimizer could get very confused, and is more than likely going to take your `and column_name = variable_of_same_name_as_column_name` to mean `and column_name = column_name`, which is probably not what you want!

ETA: If the work being done in the loop is DML, it's possible that you might be able to do away with the cursor entirely and just have a single DML statement. That would be the best scenario to use, as row-by-row processing is not the fastest thing to do in PL/SQL. Set-based processing ftw! *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze your select:

```
  SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
  FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
  WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
  AND ao_in =
                 DECODE (ao_in, 'DSSP', ao_in, get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr))
          AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
 ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;
```

The condition `ao_in = DECODE...` is always true regardless of the case expression.
The condition `t1.nr = DECODE...` can be rewritten to `t1.nr = NVL(order_in, t1.nr)`, but where is the definition of `order_in`?
Conjunction: Your case doesn't make any sense (and cannot be made in this way).

If you want to run different select statements depending on a parameter, use a where condition for this and union all such select statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parametric cursor [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#BABHBHIC)

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(ID int, name varchar(50));

INSERT INTO tbl select 1, '0011' from dual;
INSERT INTO tbl select 1, '0012' from dual;
INSERT INTO tbl select 1, '0013' from dual;
INSERT INTO tbl select 1, '0014' from dual;
INSERT INTO tbl select 2, '0015' from dual;
INSERT INTO tbl select 2, '0016' from dual;
INSERT INTO tbl select 2, '0017' from dual;


set serveroutput on
declare 
    CURSOR para_cur(num NUMBER) IS select name from tbl where id = num;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('for id = 1');
    FOR idx in para_cur(1) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(idx.name);
    end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line('for id = 2');
    FOR idx in para_cur(2) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(idx.name);
    end loop;
end;
```

out Put:

```
anonymous block completed
for id = 1
0011
0012
0013
0014
for id = 2
0015
0016
0017
```